# Spring boot: @Valid not working with @RequestHeader

Tags: spring-boot, validation

I'm really struggling to combine `@Valid` with `@RequestHeader`.
Might this be not supported or is there a way to enable it? I couldn't find useful information about that...

When I annotate the whole controller with `@Validated` it works, so it is not a big issue. However, I feel like it should work with `@Valid` as well, so I wanted to know if I'm missing something here.

Code example:

```
    @GetMapping("/validationControllerHeader")
    public String validationControllerHeader(@Valid @RequestHeader @Pattern(regexp = "[a-z]{3}[0-9]+") String someheader) {
        return someheader;
    }
```

I'm using `@Valid` in the same test controller for query parameters and body validation too and there it works, so the issue is only present with headers.

Using spring boot 2.3.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are definitely supposed to use `@Validated` in your controller class, as it indicates that the validation is meant to be performed in that class. From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation):

> To be eligible for Spring-driven method validation, all target classes need to be annotated with Spring’s `@Validated` annotation, which can optionally also declare the validation groups to use.

And, as you are using `@Pattern` (which is a Bean Validation annotation), you don't need `@Valid`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
Then I'm wondering why not having Validated on type level but Valid on parameters works for RequestParameter and RequestBody, but not RequestHeader.

I agree that Validated is the better approach, but I'm currently working on an internal library for our microservices and I know that not all devs are using it on type level in their microservices.
Wanted to make things waterproof ;)